# Using Blender GIS gives error: no imaging library available please install python GDAL or Pillow module

Tags: python

I am trying to use Blender GIS from this Repo: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

I have installed it properly and it is running in my Blender 2.79 on a MAC OS X 10.13.1 High Sierra.

When I attempt to click on Basemap  (On the left pane > GIS Tab > Basemap), I expect a dialog, but instead I get this error:

> no imaging library available please install python GDAL or Pillow module

So I proceeded to install those modules, eventually realizing that they apparently need to go in the Python packages directory for that specific Blender version, [as per this solution found here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98608/python-system-version-vs-python-blender-internal-version) In my case, the library is located within the application itself, which I accessed through right clicking the Blender icon and then **Show package contents...** with the complete path being like this.

/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/python/lib/python3.5

I then used [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip) to install in the specific directory above.

So now that I have installed Pillow and GDAL in this directory using pip, I start Blender and the same error comes up.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Download Free Image's system library (FreeImage-3.xx.dll) for your system from [here](https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/tree/master/freeimage).

Copy it to:

***your_addons_folder/BlenderGIS/core/lib/imageio/resources/freeimage***

Restart Blender then
it should work :)

Incase you are  having trouble finding where your addons are installed,
the default folder path is here;

***C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\imageio\resources***

TIP: if you can't see *AppData* unhide your system files,
on windows do:(open any folder then go to file>Options>view
thin tick "show hidden files")

If you want to know why this happened it the first place or want more info, check [here](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/265).

Hope this helps!